# How to use rebind with custom allocator and custom list

Tags: c++

I implemented my custom allocator and custom list container, which supports this allocator. They are defined like so:

```
template <typename T, size_t num_of_blocks = 16>
class MyAllocator {
public:
    template <typename U>
    struct rebind {
        using other = MyAllocator<U, num_of_blocks>;
    }
    ...dozens of standard methods
}

template <typename T, typename MyAlloc = std::allocator<Node<T>>>
class MyList {
private:
    MyAlloc allocator;
    ...different methods which use allocator member    
}
```

It all works good. So, in my client code, I can do it like:

```
auto my_list = MyList<int, MyAllocator<Node<int>,10>>{};
```

It works without errors and I see, that my custom allocator is used. But I do not like the way I use my custom allocator. In fact, I want my client code look like:

```
auto my_list = MyList<int, MyAllocator<int,10>>{};
```

My first attempt was this:

```
template <typename T, typename MyAlloc = std::allocator<T>>
class MyList {
private:
    //MyAlloc allocator; // remove this member and rebind allocator to another one
    typedef typename MyAlloc::template rebind<Node<T>>::other node_alloc_type;
    node_alloc_type allocator; // I expect that my allocator now is of type MyAllocator<Node<T>, num_of_blocks>
    ... all the rest left unchanged          
}
```

When however I run my new client code:

```
auto my_list = MyList<int, MyAllocator<int,10>>{};
```

I get these error messages:

> can not convert 'int*' to 'Node*'in assignment

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and what I'm missing. So, how can I fix it? And what is the right way to use rebind in custom container?

**EDIT**

That is how my custom container looks like now:

```
//MyList.h

#include <memory>

template<typename T> 
struct Node
{
    Node(): m_next(nullptr){}

    Node(T const &t): 
        m_value(t), 
        m_next(nullptr)
    {}

    T m_value;
    Node* m_next;
};

template<typename T, typename MyAllocator = std::allocator<Node<T>>>
class MyList
{
private:
    Node<T>* m_head = nullptr;
    Node<T>* m_tail = nullptr;
    MyAllocator my_allocator;
public:

    class Iterator 
    {
    private:
        Node<T>* m_Node; 
    public:

        Iterator(Node<T>* Node): m_Node(Node) {};

        bool operator==(const Iterator& other)
        {
            return this == &other || m_Node == other.m_Node;        
        }

        bool operator!=(const Iterator& other)
        {
            return !operator==(other);        
        }

        T operator*()
        {       
            if (m_Node)
            {
                return m_Node->m_value;
            }
            return T();
        } 

        Iterator operator++() 
        {
            Iterator i = *this;
            if (m_Node) 
            {
                m_Node = m_Node->m_next;
            }
            return i;
        }       

    };


    template<typename... Args>
    void emplace(T v)    
    {
          auto new_Node = my_allocator.allocate(1);       
          my_allocator.construct(new_Node, v);        
          if (m_head)
          {
            m_tail->m_next = new_Node;        
          } else {
            m_head = new_Node;
            new_Node->m_next = nullptr;       
          }
        m_tail = new_Node;        
    }

    Iterator begin() const
    {
        return Iterator(m_head);
    }


    Iterator end() const
    {
        return Iterator(nullptr);
    }        

};
```

At this moment there is no rebinding and I have to define it like

```
template<typename T, typename MyAllocator = std::allocator<Node<T>>>
class MyList
```

What I want is to define it like so:

```
template<typename T, typename MyAllocator = std::allocator<T>>
class MyList
```

**EDIT**

Here is a client code with standard allocator:

```
//main.cpp
#include "MyList.h"

int main()
{
    MyList<int, std::allocator<Node<int>>> my_list;
    //auto my_list = MyList<int, std::allocator<int>>; // will not work
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        my_list.emplace(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? Could you maybe provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Rakete111. I get this error, when I compile my code. The source code has dozens of hundreds of lines of code. So, I presented what really matters.

Comment: I'm totally sure, that my allocator is ok. What I do not know is how to use rebinding in custom container.

Comment: When you present what really matters, be sure it is in the form of a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I think I may know what you need, but I am not willing to do all the work of making a MCVE.

Comment: @Jive Dadson. I will provide the source code for container, since allocator does not matter.

Comment: I really have a feeling that you didn't copy the code, but just wrote it down in the question itself or something. Because one you forgot a `;` after all of the classes, and second of all, having an `int*` is maybe a sign that your allocator uses `int` instead of `Node<int>`, but wait: [your code as posted works](https://godbolt.org/g/5xr4uf).

Comment: Then post a MCVE that uses std::allocator<T>.

Comment: @Rekete1111. I presented some pseudo-code, to make it look simple and to put accent on what matters. And here is what really matters - there is no problem with allocator itself, I tested it, it works good and it has its `rebind` member. And the question is how to use this `rebind` in custom container.

Comment: The question is how to use an allocator, custom or otherwise, in your container. So post a MCVE that has a simplified version of your container, instantiated with std::allocator. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Jive Dadson. I provided the source code of my custom container.

Comment: Very good. You're getting there. Now whittle it down to "minimal" and provide a main() that exercises it.

Comment: I minimized container a little bit and provided client code with standard allocator, which shows when it works and when it does not. I need my commented code work.

Comment: main() does not compile. I'll fix it.

Comment: @Jive Dadso. Thanks for fixing!

Comment: The main question now is how to make it work =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the requirements for an allocator: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator

Notice that template rebind is optional.

Here is a list of what a container must have in order to qualify for the concept. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/AllocatorAwareContainer

Yes, gasp. I have searched in vain for a simple, or at least minimalist example. If all you need is a linked list, and you can use C++11 or later, use std::forward_list.

The following works in the example given.

```
template<typename T, typename MyAllocator = std::allocator<T>>
class MyList
{
private:
    using node_alloc_t = typename std::allocator_traits<MyAllocator>::
        template rebind_alloc<Node<T>>;

    // create an object of type node allocator
    node_alloc_t node_alloc;
    // etc ....

public:

    template<typename T>
    void emplace(T v)
    {
        Node<T>* new_Node = node_alloc.allocate(1);

        // Etc...
    }

// etc...
};
```

All together now...

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Node
{

    Node() : m_next(nullptr) {}

    Node(T const &t) :
        m_value(t),
        m_next(nullptr)
    {}

    T m_value;
    Node<T>* m_next;
};

template<typename T, typename MyAllocator = std::allocator<T>>
class MyList
{
private:
    using node_alloc_t = typename std::allocator_traits<MyAllocator>::
        template rebind_alloc<Node<T>>;

    // create an object of type node allocator
    node_alloc_t node_alloc;

public:

    class Iterator
    {
    private:
        Node<T>* m_Node;
    public:

        Iterator(Node<T>* Node) : m_Node(Node) {};

        bool operator==(const Iterator& other)
        {
            return this == &other || m_Node == other.m_Node;
        }

        bool operator!=(const Iterator& other)
        {
            return !operator==(other);
        }

        T operator*()
        {
            if (m_Node)
            {
                return m_Node->m_value;
            }
            return T();
        }

        Iterator operator++()
        {
            Iterator i = *this;
            if (m_Node)
            {
                m_Node = m_Node->m_next;
            }
            return i;
        }

    };


    template<typename T>
    void emplace(T v)
    {

        Node<T>* new_Node = node_alloc.allocate(1);
        node_alloc.construct(new_Node, v);
        if (m_head)
        {
            m_tail->m_next = new_Node;
        }
        else {
            m_head = new_Node;
            new_Node->m_next = nullptr;
        }
        m_tail = new_Node;
    }

    Iterator begin() const
    {
        return Iterator(m_head);
    }


    Iterator end() const
    {
        return Iterator(nullptr);
    }

}; 

int main()
{   
    MyList<int> my_list; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        my_list.emplace(i);
    }
    for (auto i : my_list) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tested it. It works if I put the source code of container into main.cpp. If however I put it into a separate file (as it should be), I get a list of error messages. One message says `note. in instantiation of function template specialization 'MyList...' requested here`. Other error messages say once again - `assigning to Node<int> * from type int *`

Comment: And by the way, you are using some `rebind_alloc` structure. I do not have one in my custom allocator.